# itertools tee() iterator splitting

Tags: python, python-itertools

I am confused how `tee()` really works.

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
iterators3 = itertools.tee(l, 3)
for i in iterators3:
    print (list(i))
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

This is ok. But if I try:

```
a, b, c = itertools.tee(l)
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

Why?

Comment: Where's your 3?

Comment: @MosesKoledoye yes,I got it now.

Comment: @Coldspeed `tee` does **not** return a generator object, and even if it did, you can still unpack a generator, try `head, *rest = (i for i in range(10))`, because generators are iterables...

Comment: @Tonechas Please don't make gratuitous changes to the user's code. You (and PEP-8) might prefer spaces after the commas, but it's not what the user posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tee` takes 2 arguments, an iterator and a number, it will replicate the actual iterator (with his context) the number of times you passes as argument, so you can't actually unpack more generators than tee has created:

```
a,b = tee(l) #this is ok, since it just duplicate it so you got 2 
a,b,c = tee(l, 3) #this is also ok, you will get 3 so you can unpack 3
a,b = tee(l, 3) #this will fail, tee is generating 3 but you are trying to unpack just 2 so he dont know how to unpack them
```

In python 3 you can unpack like this:

```
a, *b = tee(l, 3)
```

where `a` will hold the first iterator from `tee` and `b` will hold the rest of the iterators in a list.